# i want to generate payperiod for each month

Tags: c#, asp.net

On the first time I created pay period schedule, which is the type is Monthly, for example , Start, End, Transaction, and Functions of  pay period is like below:

1. 01-Jan-12 12:00 AM, 30-Jan-08 11:59 AM, 31-Jan-08 12:00 PM

The above one is first month payperiod. next month it ill create like this  automatically and inserted into database what i do?

1. 01-Feb-12 12:00 AM,28-Feb-12 11:59 PM,29-Feb-12 12:00 PM

please help me..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186794/how-can-i-get-correct-payperiod-from-date

Comment: read my updated question please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; ++i)
{
    DateTime firstDate = new DateTime(2012, i, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(2012, i);
    DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2012, i, daysInMonth-1, 23, 59, 59);
    DateTime TransactionDate = new DateTime(2012, i, daysInMonth, 0, 0, 0);
    Console.WriteLine(firstDate.ToString() + 
                "," + endDate.ToString() + 
                "," + TransactionDate.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It returns the following error {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.

Comment: @Fernando sorry i had a mistake I edited the code.